# rt_sigreturn and linux kernels

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I see that some linux kernels use sys_sigreturn, some have sys_rt_sigreturn and some have support for both. What is the fundamental difference between the two? Why are there 2 system calls that do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

According to `sigreturn` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigreturn.2.html), `rt_sigreturn` is advanced variant of `sigreturn` which supports enlarged signal type:

> The original Linux system call was named sigreturn().  However, with
>          the addition of real-time signals in Linux 2.2, a new system call,
>          rt_sigreturn() was added to support an enlarged sigset_t type.  The
>          GNU C library hides these details from us, transparently employing
>          rt_sigreturn() when the kernel provides it.